# How to express the good in difference?

Tags: word-order, translation

One of the local companies has a slogan that literally translates to

> We are all different... fortunately

I sense that "fortunately we are all different" sounds better in English. However, it misses the order of conveying the information:

- we are all different
- and that's not a bad thing at all

**Question:** How to express the good in difference? (within provided context)

Comment: 'We are all special'.

Comment: Especially as a _slogan_ (where you're allowed more leeway than formal writing) I think the literal translation you give works quite well. Possibly _luckily_ or _thankfully_ as alternatives to _fortunately_.

Comment: @TripeHound - sounds like a good answer for me.

Comment: If you use "luckily" or "thankfully" I recommend changing around the wording so that it is not perceived as "Thank god we're different, 'cause who'd want to be you?"  Perhaps "Thankfully we are all different"

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the company does and why they've chosen this specific slogan. There might be something more idiomatic in English that relates to the product being advertised.

Comment: @Tom - it is selling furniture for both private individuals and companies + other interior design products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression **vive la difference** has been added to the lexicon.

From [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vive_la_difference):

> *vive la difference* [exclamation] humorous
>
> An expression of approval of difference, especially that between the
>   sexes.

The positive aspects of there being differences are obviously highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good way to do this that will fit within a short length.

"Our differences are positive."
"Our differences paint a complete picture."
"Differences are what make us unique."
"Without our differences, there would be no 'you' or 'me'."

Answer (score 1):

Especially as a *slogan* (where you're allowed more leeway than formal writing) I think the literal translation you give works quite well.

Possibly substituting *luckily* or *thankfully* as alternatives to *fortunately*.